# Rspec Capybara find field not functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm running Rails 4 using capybara and rspec (OS is Ubuntu 13.10).  I'm having a problem -- when I run rspec my specs work, including those that use capybara's fill_in methods.  However in one spec I need to use capybara's find_field method, and it is not functioning at all.  It gives me the following error:

```
Failure/Error: page.find_field('From:').set(Date.today - 1.month)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "From:"
```

Now, I have inserted a "puts page.html" line immediately before the page.find_field... line and the html it prints includes the following lines:

```
<div class="date-range-picker">
<span class="from-date"><label for="from_date">From:</label> <input id="from_date"    name="from_date" type="date" value="2013-12-23" /></span>
 <span class="to-date"><label for="to_date">To:</label> <input id="to_date"  name="to_date" type="date" value="2013-12-30" /></span>
 </div>
```

So the element is there, but not being picked up by the find_field method.  Any ideas?

Comment: If various selectors can't help, the problem may not be there. Please paste full code of that example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, after much meandering through `Capybara`'s source files I found the problem.  It seems that the `#find_field` method doesn't work properly when using `Capybara-webkit`.  The method only failed on examples that had the js: true argument, so that should have been the first clue. Anyway it seems that the cause of this is some method naming conflict between `capybara` and `capybara-webkit`, but I didn't analyze it too closely and so I can't be sure.

I changed the `find_field('from_date')` to `find('#from_date')` and everything works now. It also worked when changing to the `:rack_test` driver, but since I need webkit that's what I'll stick too. Is this issue documented anywhere??

Answer (score 1):

As for capybara [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find_field-instance_method):

"Find a form field on the page. The field can be found by its name, id or label text."

so use this code instead:

```
page.find_field('form_date').set(Date.today - 1.month)
```

So you are selecting the field by it's id.

Comment: Tried that.  Same result.  The code above is finding by label text, which according to your quote should work.

Answer (score 0):

I placed your HTML fragment within an HTML page and was able to successfully do a `find_field('From:')` on it, which suggests the problem lies within the containing HTML. My "idea" would be to strip down the page until the `find_field` succeeds as a means of isolating the offending content.

Comment: What exactly is a locator?  If you mean the name or id of the element (in this case "from_date"), I've already tried that, it gives me the same results.

Comment: The string I passed to the method is the label text, which according to Capybara's docs should work.

Comment: You're right, provided it's part of an enclosing <form> field, as discussed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another site and it slightly worked for me:

Add this to "support/select_from_chosen.rb":

```
module SelectFromChosen
  # select_from_chosen('Option', from: 'id_of_field')
  def select_from_chosen(item_text, options)
    field = find_field(options[:from], :visible => false)
    find("##{field[:id]}_chosen").click
    find("##{field[:id]}_chosen ul.chosen-results li", :text => item_text).click
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SelectFromChosen, type: :feature
end
```

I was able to do:

```
select_from_chosen('Blue', from: 'car_colors')
find('#submit-button').click
expect(page).to have_content 'Blue'
select_from_chosen('Red', from: 'car_colors')
find('#submit-button').click
expect(page).to have_content 'Red'
```

What I was actually trying to do was validate that the options in the chosen results where available for some users and not for others so I wound up using:

```
find('#car_colors_chosen').click
expect(page).to have_content 'Blue'
expect(page).not_to have_content 'Gold'
```

Just wanted to add this incase it helped someone else,